# How can I display full urls in Apache mod_status output?

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there anyway to get full urls displayed on the mod_status output page? At the moment the request is truncated at 64 chars:

```
HEAD /w3c-validator/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fans
```

I know there's a bunch of query string options like ?auto, ?notable etc, but none of them show the full urls (that I can see).

Answer (score 5):

as Apache docs said :

Determine if **mod_status** displays *the first 63 characters* of a request or
the last 63, assuming the request itself is greater than 63 chars.
ths Default value is **Off**.

just change the value to **On**.
the sample config like this:

```
<IfModule mod_status.c>

 <Location /server-status>
  SetHandler server-status
 </Location>

 # Keep track of extended status information for each request
 ExtendedStatus On

 SeeRequestTail On
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: The drawback is that you will not get the full URL, but just the tail of the URL. I think there is no option to get the full URL. I usually take the url sample and grep it in the apache log to get the full URL.

Comment: The problem with grepping the apache log for the full URL is that URLs which do not complete are not logged. So if you are troubleshooting an instance where a page request makes an httpd process grow very large and get killed by the OS before the page request completes and you need to full URL to reproduce the issue and see what SQL query is being built, this is very problematic.

Comment: Wow, what a colossally idiotic implementation by Apache here. You can see the beginning, the end, but not the whole thing. What year is it?